# Pass formData with another data in ajax with codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have develop ajax upload with upload library in coodeigniter.

This is the data that I grab with jquery :

```
        var inputFile = $('input#file');
        var filesToUpload = inputFile[0].files;
        // make sure there is file(s) to upload
        if (filesToUpload.length > 0) {
            // provide the form data that would be sent to sever through ajax
            var formData = new FormData();

            for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
                var file = filesToUpload[i];
                formData.append("file[]", file, file.name);
            }
```

This is my ajax :

```
$.ajax({
   url: "<?php echo base_url('surveyor/c_surveyor/add_file_image'); ?>",
   type: 'post',
   data: formData,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   success: function () {
         $(":file").val('');
         $(":text").val('');
         $("#tableClean").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
         $("#tableReport").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
         $("#addRow").attr("disabled", false);
         $("#addClean").attr("disabled", false);

         $('#pilih_isotank').after('<div class="callout callout-success lead" id="div_error"><p id="pesan_error">Semua Data Berhasil Terupload</p></div>');
         $('#div_error').fadeIn("fast");
         $('#pesan_error').html(obj.Message);
         $('#div_error').fadeOut(7000);
         myArrays = [];
        }
});
```

I have a problem with this, how to pass another data in $ajax ilike this :

```
data: formData, EIR_REF : $('#no_eir').val();
```

I try to acces this `EIR_REF` like this on this url :

```
public function add_file_image(){
   echo $this->input->post('EIR_REF');
}
```

It gives me nothing. How can I make it true ?

Answer (score 1):

formData.append will work as well.
Just add the code below outside the loop before posting to server.

```
formData.append('EIR_REF', $('#no_eir').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the formdata in a separate field and the extra field can append as shown below. And in the serever side you can access accordingly. Try this:

```
data: {formData:formData, EIR_REF : $('#no_eir').val()};
```

Comment: Please, explain your answer.[From review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10532945).

Comment: it gives me result of echo is ["index.html"]